# ResolveChoice specs cast to decimal with precision & scale

Tags: aws-glue

I'm trying to cast a field in my dynamic frame to decimal with a specific precision and scale. When I set the datatype to decimal, it does indeed get cast to a decimal. However, precision and scale are not defined. When I try to set the precision and scale I receive an exception.

```
df = ResolveChoice.apply(
    frame=df,
    specs = [
        ("price", "cast:decimal(6,2)")]
    )
```

> pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: u'Invalid decimal specification decimal(6, 2). Should be decimal(precision, scale)'

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: Nope, I just switched data types :-\

Comment: I realised that the precision defaults to (10,2) and there doesn't seem to be a way to tweak it

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same error when calling apply_mapping function. What I observed there must be no space between precision and scale.

This will throw error

```
decimal(6, 2)
```

whereas following not

```
decimal(6,2)
```

I know that in question there is no whitespace in a code but there is whitespace in error message.